# MySQL Query using escaped $_SESSION var returns boolean?

Tags: php, arrays, session, mysqli

I'm having a little bit of trouble. I need to return a set of data in a table.

Quickly here is the table structure -

```
DB ->
users -> user_id , user_name , user_pass , user_email ;
urls -> user_id , url , title ;
```

On the page I have the currently logged in users, user_id inside a $_SESSION variable - SESSION 'user_id'. I need to return all the (url)s inside the urls table that have the same matching user_id as the one set in the SESSION variable. Here's the code I have and it almost works, but says when I'm trying to fetch an array it is getting a boolean from $results. Any help will be greatly appreciated! The last line print_r is there just to see what is being returned.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM url WHERE user_id = ";
$sql .= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_SESSION['user_id']);
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
print_r($row);
```

Here is the error I am getting -

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in     C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\include\feed.php on line 10
```

Line 10 is this line...

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Thanks again!

Comment: So $result doesn't represent a "valid result" - i.e. an error occured. *What* is the error? (Most tutorials show how to "handle query errors", perhaps with a `die`.) Anyway, note that *using placeholders is the correct practice* and the code given is *still vulnerable to injection* and invalid SQL syntax because the value is not quoted. Using mysql_real_escape_string in this aspect (for a supposedly numeric value no less) just highlights the misunderstanding.

Comment: Why does nobody ever check the returned result from `mysqli_query`? If you did you'd see that the query has failed and mysqli_error() has a description of the error, which is almost certainly a syntax error in your query. Go and extend your code to do some proper error checking, and come back with a sensible question!

Comment: @user2246674 - Hmm, I having a little trouble understanding exactly what you mean, do you have a link to documentation you'd recommend.

Comment: @Gk3Biz See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php - note the "if" statements used, along with discussion of the return value. Following the code in the provided link (and elsewhere) will yield and idiom similar to `$r = mysqli_query($DBlink,$q) or die(mysqli_error($DBlink)." Q=".$q);`. Of course including the query is optional. Handling an "invalid query" in some fashion - die/log or program logic - is not.

Comment: @Mike W - I assumed the query had an error, I just wasn't sure where it was. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$escapedID = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_SESSION['user_id']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM url WHERE user_id = '".$escapedID."'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
print_r($row);
```

Comment: Wow, still got the same error and realized this entire time the SELECT * from url was wrong - it was meant to be urls. Very sorry guys, thank you for your help. I still went with your code just cause it seemed to be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query()` returns `FALSE` on failure. See the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). The query is might be failing because you've written "url" in the `FROM` clause; you have the table name listed as "urls" above.